# Possible to publish app on my own device (iPad 1st Generation 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Xcode version 9.1; High Sierra 10.13; iPad (1st Generation) iOS 5.1.1

The iPad I'm using is not a model that is supported by this version of Xcode. Is it possible for me to publish an app for personal use onto my older iOS 5.1.1 device? I prefer not to bust out an older computer to download < XCode 7 to support 5.1.1 (XCode 7 and under are not supported on High Sierra).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install the app on the old versions as Xcode will only support the latest versions that is bind with it. Apple always updates it operating system at that time they also give an update for Xcode and if there is inconsistancy in the version it will not allow to work.

**it's only possible if you have an older version of Mac with the older version of Xcode and older version of iPad. (hard to find)... hope this gets you well cheers :)**